# How do I pass the navigate prop to a child component that is dynamically rendered in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a simple app that has 4 pages:
Intro
Homescreen
StoreA
StoreB

StoreA contains a Header and Storelist.  Storelist is comprised of all the stores located in a certain area.  Using Redux, I've made it so when a user clicks on an individual store, details of the store are made visible(quite similar to Stephen Grider's techStack tutorial).  I would like to pass the navigation prop all the way down to CardSection that contains the details when it's clicked on.  How would I pass the navigate prop from StoreA->StoreList->IndividualStore->StoreDetails so that I can create a button for a user to navigate back to the HomeScreen?

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you have a few options,
the first one is to pass down the prop: this.props.navigation to the child component from the screen which is the parent of this child and if it's nested inside another component you just keep propagating the navigation prop down.

another option is to keep in a mobx/redux store a ref to the navigation of the navigator like so:

```
<Navigator ref={ref=>saveRefInStore(ref._navigation)} screenProps={/* props if needed */}/>
```

another option is to use this library, [rn-navigation-store](https://github.com/himelbrand/rn-navigation-store), that manages the navigation for you including nested navigators and persistence if you want.

using this library you are able to navigate from every component you want.

[here is a link to the github repo](https://github.com/himelbrand/rn-navigation-store)

of course there are more options, but I think these options will help you